# Jenkins shell command work flow

Tags: jenkins

Under the link http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#shellcommand,

in the shell command it states that

> On Windows, commands are run via cmd.exe /c which works well. However, if you're running a batch file, the error level does not get propagated correctly unless you add 'call' before your batch file's name: cmd=['call', 'myfile.bat', ...].

It says that the commands are executed cmd.exe.

I assume the cmd.exe is located in the c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe, am i right or it calls from some other location like in the windows startup .

Answer (score 0):

The cmd.exe is the one found in the system path variable PATH for the Jenkins process.  On my machine it is in C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.